# I have hit an AngularJS wall

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-route-segment

I am trying to pick AngularJS back up.  I created a site with a previous version of AngularJS and RequireJS and never had this issue, I have searched and searched and still cannot get this to work so I am reaching out.  I am trying to use RequireJS 2.1.15 and AngularJS 1.3.11.  When trying to load up my main page I am getting the following:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module rehyveApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:63:12
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:1764:17
at ensure (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:1688:38)
at module (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:1762:14)
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4094:22
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:323:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4078:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4095:40
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:323:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4078:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngRoute&p1=Error%3…dules%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A64216%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular.js%3A4078%3A5)
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:63:12
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4117:15
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:323:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4078:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4095:40
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:323:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4078:5)
at createInjector (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:4004:11)
at doBootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:1446:20)
at Object.bootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:64216/js/lib/angular.js:1467:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=rehyveApp&p1=Error…trap%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A64216%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular.js%3A1467%3A12)
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#/main">Load Main View</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

    <script src="js/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my main.js:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    base: "/js",
    lib: "/js/lib"
},
shim: {
    'lib/bootstrap': {
        deps: ['lib/jquery']
    },
    'lib/angular': {
        deps: ['lib/jquery']
    },
    'lib/angular-route': {
        deps: ['lib/angular']
    },
    'lib/angular-resource': {
        deps: ['lib/angular']
    },
    'lib/ui-bootstrap': {
        deps: ['lib/angular']
    },
    'base/app': {
        deps: ['lib/angular', 'lib/angular-route']
    },
    'base/controllers/mainController': {
        deps: ['base/app']
    }
  }
});

define(['lib/jquery', 'lib/angular', 'lib/angular-route', 'lib/angular-resource', 'lib/ui-bootstrap', 'base/app', 'base/controllers/mainController'], function () {
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     angular.module('rehyveApp', ['ngRoute']);
     angular.bootstrap(document, ['rehyveApp']);
   });
});
```

Here is my app.js:

```
'use strict';

define(['lib/angular'], function () {
var rehyveApp = angular.module('rehyveApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/main',
            {
                templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'main'});


    });
return rehyveApp;
});
```

and my mainController.js:

'use strict';

```
define(['base/app'], function (rehyveApp) {
var rehyveApp = angular.module('rehyveApp',[]);
rehyveApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.testdata = {
        name: 'mainController working'
    }
}]);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that it was an issue with the 1.3.11 version of the angular-route.js lib, they just released a 1.3.12 and after copying that in, everything is working now.  Thank you all for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `'lib/angular-route'` in your `define` at `app.js`. See that you are using `ngRoute` but not importing it.

```
define(['lib/angular','lib/angular-route'], function () {
```

Comment: I absolutely did, thank you for that, however I am still getting the same error after adding the import.

Comment: @Vessaredan clean your cache and are you getting the same error ? `Module 'ngRoute' is not available!`

Comment: yeah I even used a different browser and I still get the same error